# why do other events cannot be fired while "for loop" is in process?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a for loop and when the  loop is being processed, I cant access any other function or event like clicking button it doesn't work till the for loop ends. Is there any way to overcome this Issue and hope I can get answer soon.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < sizes - 2; i++)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                trackBar1.Value = trackBar1.Value + 1;
                DisplayImage(_image);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The term you're looking for is "multi-threading."

Comment: you cannot update the UI on the main thread and have interactions with it, use BackgroundWorker or Task library functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi if you using framework 4.5
you can to the next :

```
  Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizes - 2; i++)
            {
                if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                {
                     trackBar1.Value = trackBar1.Value + 1;
                     DisplayImage(_image);
                }
            }
        });
```

if not you can try this using thread :

```
  Thread thread = new Thread(NewMethod);
        thread.Start();

 private void NewMethod()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes - 2; i++)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                trackBar1.Value = trackBar1.Value + 1;
                DisplayImage(_image);
            }
        }
    }
```

you can upgrade but you need to do it with delegate try this if you have cross thread operation error when update ui : 
create delegate void function

```
 delegate void Function();
```

then in your for make this :

```
 Invoke(new Function(delegate()
            {
               label.text = "some text" ;
            }));
```

Comment: Do you think it is OK to update UI controls in background threads/tasks ? A quick test for WinForms apps: `new Thread(() => { this.Text = "aaa";  }).Start();`

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to create a new thread in .NET Framework. First, create a new ThreadStart delegate. The delegate points to a method that will be executed by the new thread. Pass this delegate as a parameter when creating a new Thread instance. Finally, call the Thread.Start method to run your method (in this case WorkThreadFunction) on background.

```
using System.Threading;

Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
thread.Start();
```

The WorkThreadFunction could be defined as follows.

```
public void WorkThreadFunction()
{
  try
  {
    // do any background work
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // log errors
  }
}
```